# Align equations already created with {equation*}?

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex, tinytex

I think this is simple.

I am using LaTeX in Rmarkdown, with the `amsmath` package. I am using `\begin{equation} XX \end{equation}` so that I can label my equations throughout the document.

However, I have a set of equations that I would like aligned for simplicity. I have tried the following:

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{equation}
\frac{dF}{dt} &= - j_{FI}
\end{equation} \\
\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= j_{VG}
\end{equation} 
\end{align*}
```

But it won't run. I get the following error:
`LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.`  I can either `align{}` or do `equation{}` but not both. Any insight?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. In the title you talk about `equation*`, in the body you have `equation`. In the text you talks about `align`, in the code you have `align*`.  One needs a very good crystal ball to make sense of this ...

Comment: ((Edit: I also thought that align and equation were independent functions- hence why I was trying to combine them. I didn't realize they could do complementary functions...))

I apologize, I actually was so unfamiliar with it that I didn't realize they were separate arguments, and then when I edited, I didn't change the title. I thought people were saying the ``*`` to indicate it was a function and then input. I'll fix the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `*` to the normal `align` environment, you remove the numbering and possibility to use labels. Just don't do that if you want to label your expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
%\begin{equation}
\frac{dF}{dt} &= - j_{FI}\label{eq1}
%\end{equation} 
\\
%\begin{equation}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= j_{VG}\label{eq2}
%\end{equation} 
\end{align}


\ref{eq1}


\ref{eq2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I've been banging my head to get this to work. Two questions: I was able to get this to work without the ``ref{eq1}`` lines- as in the number still worked and did not mess up later numbering on the sections I do not need aligned. What it its purpose?

Second question, what do you mean by "if I don't want to label my expressions"? I feel like that must not mean the equation # label itself, right? (Sorry, fairly new to LaTeX)

Comment: Oops, three questions. I tried some googling but still unsure. What does the % do to the ``\begin{equation}`` code? Clearly that is the major piece I was missing...

Comment: @lmbradley The `\ref` was just to show that the label work. By "Just don't do that if you want to label your expressions:" I meant don't add stars if you want numbering

Comment: The `%` are comment characters. You can also remove the lines instead of commenting them.

Comment: @lmbradley Maybe to expand a bit on the terminology:  the numbering besides the equation, e.g. `(1)` is normally called "tag". In the latex world, label usually means `\label{SomeWordHere}`, which then can be used in your text with `See equation \ref{SomeWordHere}`.

Comment: Ah so essentially, in the future I just use {align} and then use the ``\label`` feature to add equation labels, and my future ``{equation}`` bits will auto-detect my labels and continue numbering?

Comment: Yes, align and equation use the same counter, so the numbering will continue

Comment: The `\label{...}` bit is optional. You only need it if you want to refer to the number somewhere in the text using `\ref{...}`